# Rails will_paginate update pagination after creating record with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm developing a crud app using AJAX.  I'm using will_paginate to page the results.  The behavior I'm running into is that when I create a record and display that record in my view, it prepends the record to the table, but it doesn't pop the last record to the next page.

The same happens with delete, with the opposite behavior. I'm guessing I need to render the whole table again after create, but I'm not sure the best way to handle it. Any ideas?

When Page Loads:

[image: On Page Load]

After Creating a Few Records:

[image: After Creating A few Records]

Here is code from my controller, view, and javascript. I did not include the form partial.

view:

```
<tbody id="payees">
  <%= render @payees %>
</tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">
        <%= will_paginate @payees, remote: true %>
     </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

create.js.coffee

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @payee )%>").prependTo("#payees")
$('#new_payee')[0].reset()
```

payees_controller

```
def index
  @payees = Payee.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
  @payee = Payee.new
end

def create
  @payee = Payee.new(payee_params)

  respond_to do |format|
      if @payee.save
        format.html { redirect_to @payee, notice: 'Payee was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @payee, status: :created, location: @payee }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @payee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

**Edit:**

> I was able to get it working by retrieving all records after the new record was saved. The caveat to this is it seems it is an unnecessary query on the database. Is there a more efficient way?

controller:

```
.
.
.
if @payee.save
    @payees = Payee.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order("created_at DESC")

    format.html { redirect_to @payee, notice: 'Payee was successfully created.' }
    format.js {}
    format.json { render json: @payee, status: :created, location: @payee }
else
.
.
.
```

> I changed create.js.coffee:

```
$("#payees").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @payees )%>")
$('#new_payee')[0].reset()
```

Comment: You answer your own question: Generally retrieving the records from the DB is necessary. Specifically you need to do it on delete, because you don't have enough records to display. On Add you could simply remove the last as you add the first.

Comment: If I remove the last one after create, it won't be at the top of the 2nd page unless I retrieve the records correct? i'll test

Comment: Remove it from the HTML, not from the DB. When you request the 2nd page, it will be there. Similarly, you could assume the N+1 record returns the first element in the second page and load that one when deleting, but this assume no one else is adding records while you are.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That's awesome